# Android perform exit Animation without finish the activity

Tags: java, android, animation

I have two activities let's call them Act1 and Act2.
Act2 is called in Act1 using startActivity().
And I call      overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right) right after I call startActivity().
The promblem is , the exit animation, which is a slide out effect in this case, is not working. Act2 just slides in but Act1 doesn't slide out.

I think the reason why Act1 doesn't slide out is that it is still in the Activity Stack . If I call finish() right after startActivity(), the animation works well. But if I press back button in the Act2 then, the app exits instead of returning to the Act1. This is not what I want .
Is there any way to perform the exit animation without calling finish()?

Answer (score 0):

What if you finish the activity and instead of navigating back you start a new intent to act1? You could overide on back hit event as well so that you could get either back button or navigation back button.

Comment: But if I finish and  start a new intent to act1, the information in act1 will be lost. Maybe I can save the information using savedInstanceState or bundle.But there will be  more extra work I should do if I use this. Is there more effective way? Anyway , thank you : )

Comment: You could just pass the data you need forward through the bundle back into activity 1.